# Stokes' theorem in complex coordinates (CFT)

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, complex-numbers

I am studying CFT, where I encounter Stokes' theorem in complex coordinates:
$$
\int_R (\partial_zv^z + \partial_{\bar{z}}v^{\bar{z}})dzd\bar{z} = i \int_{\partial R}(v^{z}d\bar{z} - v^{\bar{z}}dz).
$$
I am trying to prove this by starting from the form of Stokes'/Greens theorem:
$$
\int_R(\partial_xF^y - \partial_yF^x)dxdy = \int_{\partial R}(F^xdx + F^ydy
$$
and transforming to complex coordinates. The reason I ask this here and not on Math exchange is that in CFT we have the distinction between indices up and indices down:
$$
v^z = v^{\tau}+iv^{\sigma} \\ v^{\bar{z}} = v^{\tau} - iv^{\sigma} \\ v_z = v^{\tau}-iv^{\sigma} \\ v_{\bar{z}} = v^{\tau} + iv^{\sigma}$$,
with $z = \tau +i\sigma$ and $\bar{z} = \tau - i\sigma$.
The substitution is kind of straight forward, but I get:
$$
\int_R(\partial_zv^{z} - \partial_{\bar{z}}v^{\bar{z}})dzd\bar{z} = i\int_{\partial R}v^zd\bar{z}+v^{\bar{z}}dz,
$$
so I get two relative minus signs wrong. As the calculation is not so difficult, I have the feeling I am missing something crucial here. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your expression of  standard Stokes theorem is false : index are not coherent and not correct. The correct expression is :

$\int_R(\partial_xF_y - \partial_yF_x)dxdy = \int_{\partial R}(F_xdx + F_ydy)$

Comment: I would say that the complex form of the theorem is simpler so you are carrying coal to Newscastle if you're converting it to the higher-dimensional real case.

Comment: And, for your final formula, if you make the transformation $w^z = v^z$, $w^{\bar z} = -v^{\bar z}$, it seems that you get the correct formula.

Comment: Hi @Erik, which references are you using?

Comment: @LubošMotl offtopic: Thanks for learning me an awesome English saying - I will definitely use it :) ontopic: you are right, but still I should be able to do the calculation this way around as well

Comment: @Trimok yes this substitution seems to work

Comment: @Qmechanic David Tong's chapter 4, http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html and Polchinski's String Theory (Volume 1)

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71168/

Answer (score 2):

I think I can help. Pick up the expression you started with. Convert to coordinates $\tau$ and $\sigma$ as you did. Use the Green's theorem in these coordinates and then convert back to the complex coordinates again. I am not good with word by this transliterates in the following expression

$$2∫∫dσ dτ (∂_{σ}v^{σ} + ∂_{τ}v^{τ})$$ = (now use Green’s theorem and the next integral is a contour counterclockwise bounding the area defined by the previous double integral 
$$= 2∫ [v^{σ} dτ - v^{τ} dσ] .$$
Now convert back to $v^{z}$ and $v^{\bar z}$ and to the differentials ($dz$,  $d\bar z$) and you get to the correct result.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. This site supports [mathjax](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for writing mathematical symbols. Please use it instead of unicode.